# How to use Rhino Mocks to Mock an HttpContext.Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rhino-mocks, httpcontext

I'm new to Mocking frameworks and have started using RhinoMocks to assist with my MVC App Unit Testing.

I'm using [Scott Hanselmanns MVC Mock Helper](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) to assist in mocking the HttpContext.
I've succesfully (after some time) mocked some of what I need but have come unstuck when it comes to the Application property of the HttpContext.

In my application I store an object in the Application and retrieve it within a Controller like:

```
SomeObj foo = (SomeObj)Application["fooKey"];
```

This gets created on Application_Start in my MVC App.

**UPDATED FOLLOWING FIRST ANSWER** (additional code for clarity)
Currently in the test setup I do:

```
HttpContextBase mockHttpBase = mocks.FakeHttpContext();
controllerToTest = new SomeController();
mocks.SetFakeControllerContext(controllerToTest);


HttpApplicationStateBase appState = 
    MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpApplicationStateBase>();

Globals tmpAppGlobals = 
    new Globals();

mockHttpBase.Expect(ctx => ctx.Application).Return(appState);
mockHttpBase.Expect(ctx => ctx.Application[Globals.GlobalsKey]).
    Return(tmpAppGlobals);
```

In my unit test setup I do:

```
Globals tmpAppGlobals = new Globals();
controllerToTest.ControllerContext.HttpContext.
            Expect(ctx => ctx.Application[Globals.GlobalsKey]).
Return(tmpAppGlobals);
```

This call throws a NullReference Exception, for the Application object.

My question is two fold:

1) Is this the right approach or have I done something wrong from a design / architecture perspective?

2) Why doesn't this work?!

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I've edited my answer; check it and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Without delving too deeply, this looks mostly correct.

The Application property is virtual on HttpContextBase, so you should be able to set up a return value for it from Rhino -- Assuming you're mocking HttpContextBase as Scott Hanselmanns post does.

Some possible causes, which are really just guesses from lack of information:

- Did you set up returns for
  controllerToTest.ControllerContext?
- Did you set up a return for *that*
  objects HttpContext property?
- Did you set up a return for *that*
  objects Application property?

The reason I ask is that typically when you do expectation setups, you already have references to the objects that will be called as part of your test, so you wouldn't do a property chain like you do with your `controllerToTest.ControllerContext.HttpContext.
            Expect()` call.

**Edit:**

I think I see the problem, and I think it's with this part:

`Expect(ctx => ctx.Application[Globals.GlobalsKey])`

I think you're assuming that indexers work the same as properties, when they don't. What you really need to do is set up an expectation on your `appState` object to receive a call to the Item property, like this:

```
// setup expectations -- assumes some of the expectations and mocks 
// the from original question
mockHttpBase.Expect(ctx => ctx.Application).Return(appState);
appState.Expect(ctx => ctx.Item(Globals.GlobalsKey)).Return(tmpAppGlobals);

// run the test
```

Comment: Randolpho, thanks. 
I have setup the returns for the controller context, httpContext and the application [I think]. I've added some additional code for clarity.

Comment: Thanks again Randolpho. I couldn't get your example to work, unfortunately. I have since reverted to writing my own Mock objects for the HttpContext and child objects and am having more success doing things that way.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the below for Moq.  It took me awhile how to mock the HttpApplication, and the appState.Object is the return method duh!

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new FakeHttpSessionState();
        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        var appState = new Mock<HttpApplicationStateBase>();

        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Application).Returns(appState.Object);

        //emulate session (HttpContext.Current.Session) 
        var contx = new HttpContext(new MyApp.NUnit.Tests.Fakes.FakeHttpWorkerRequest());
        contx.Items["AspSession"] = CreateSession();

        HttpContext.Current = contx;

        return context.Object;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I am dense where is "FakeHttpSessionState" and "CreateSession" defined?